# why structure address not equals after assignment in the following case

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    struct my_structure {
        char name[20];
        int number;
        int rank;
    };

    struct my_structure var = {"Stud", 35, 1};
    struct my_structure *ptr;
    ptr = &var;

    printf("%p ", &var);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%p ", &ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is complied under c99. **ptr** are not equal to **var**. why?

---

0x7ffeea577988

---

0x7ffeea577978

Comment: You print the addresses of 2 variables. How should it be possible for 2 variables to share the same memory location?

Comment: Sidenote: the code invokes undefined behaviour. `%p` expects a `void *`. That's one of the very rare case you have to cast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With

```
printf("%p ", &ptr);
```

you don't print where `ptr` is pointing, you print the location of the `ptr` variable.

If you want both `printf` calls to print the same thing, you should not use the address-of operator:

```
printf("%p ", ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

After this assignment

```
ptr = &var;
```

the variable `ptr` stores the address of the variable `var`. So to output the address using the variable `ptr` you should output the value in `ptr`.

Also take into account that the address of an object of a structure type is equal to the address of the first member of the object.

And at last according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    struct my_structure
    {
        char name[20];
        int number;
        int rank;
    };

    struct my_structure var = {"Stud", 35, 1};
    struct my_structure *ptr;
    ptr = &var;

    printf("%p\n", ( void * )&var);
    printf("%p\n", ( void * )ptr);
    printf( "%p\n", ( void * )var.name );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
0x7ffce8ed4f10
0x7ffce8ed4f10
0x7ffce8ed4f10
```

As you can see the three addresses are equal each other.